# Why All-For-One goes for a full frontal assault against All Might?

Tags: my-hero-academia

It was very strange to see All-For-One (who make possess large number of different quirks) choosing a brute-force way (all kind of power-ups to increase strength).

It feel like there should be amazing (almost unbeatable) combinations of quirks. As an example - Invisibility + Warp + Compression + Multiple hands.

You come to some place (invisible), open multiple warp gates, use your multiple hands to touch and compress all your enemies at the same time.

Gave over.

Comment: I wouldn't assume All for One necessarily intended to win. After all, he seemed aware that All Might have away One for All, so what's the point of fighting him at all?

Comment: He won against Nana Shimura, who also had One for All, and even though he couldnt beat All Might in their former battle, now All Might was injured, with One for All leftovers and he (One for All) obtained several new force increasing quirks. So I think he intended to win and personally I believe other kinds of attacks dont combine their power like quirks who increase strenght. He also was close to win, like Nomu and Tomura who he created were also close to win. In a way he won because he retired All Might, though All Might had a bigger win since he retired and imprisioned him and saved Bakugo

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remember that in that fight, AFO (All For One) wanted to take away everything All Might had been trying to protect, one by one, starting with his pride. AFO wanted to destroy All Might's image as the Peace symbol, bring fear into the hearts of the people and lose their hopes in him to create a breach in the society.